# Compute discrete sequence from equation in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I Need to develop the scilab code for the following problem solution.
System under consideration is

x_(n+1) = a*x_n+μ,   for x_n ≤ 0

b*x_n+μ-1, for x_n > 0

x_(n+1) is calculated depending on the  x_n values in each iteration

The code needs to do the following steps:

Let initial value of x_n=0;then

First iteration n=0:

As x_n ≤ 0,
x_(n+1) = a*x_n + µ → x_1 = a*x_0 + µ

Consider that x1 >0

Second Iteration n=1:

x_(n+1) = b*x_n + µ-1 → x_2 = b*x_1 + µ-1 → x2 = b*(a*x_0+µ) + µ-1

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. What have you tried so far? What problems did you find with your approach? We could help you find errors and understand mistakes you may have made, but we should not do it from scratch for you.

Comment: You should at least give typical values for  a,b and μ

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you expect but the following should do what you want, just replace the values of parameters by your values:

```
a = -1;
b = -2;
mu = 0.5;
x = 0;
for n=1:10
    if x(n) <= 0
        x(n+1) = a*x(n)+mu;
    else
        x(n+1) = b*x(n)+mu-1;
    end
end

disp(x)
```

it yields

```
   0.
   0.5
  -1.5
   2.
  -4.5
   5.
  -10.5
   11.
  -22.5
   23.
  -46.5
```

Comment: Thank u sir for your solution . but what i want to know is , to write the equation with symbolic objects. Here i am pasting scilab code which is executed in console and error shown in console window                                                                                               
 m='m'
 m  =   "m"

--> x='x'
 x  =  "x"

--> y='y'
 y  =   "y"

--> y=m*x

and message shown that                                                                                         
Undefined operation for the given operands.
check or define function %c_m_c for overloading.

Comment: First, Scilab cannot manage symbolic objects. And secondly, you cannot obtain a symbolic expression since the sign of x_n is not known in advance.

Comment: Can't we handle linear equation in SCI lab. and how to overload function in SCI Lab

Comment: See the overloading features in the doc: `help overloading`. However, be warned that your discrete equation is *not* linear because of the switch depending on sign of iterate.